# Synchronized view between *.h and *.cpp file in qt creator

Tags: c++, qt-creator

Is that possible to synchronized view when splitted between *h. and *.cpp file in qtcreator? (When I'will open *.h file in one view then automatic will open *.cpp file in second view).

Comment: Can you find that option in the application's settings? If yes, "yes, it's possible". If no, "no, it's not".

Comment: https://doc.qt.io/qtcreator/creator-coding-navigating.html No evidence of such a feature.